# Ruby on rails tutorial chapter 12 random unrelated errors created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

This is my first foray into app development, and I have been following Michael Hartl's tutorial pretty much verbatim. All went fine until towards the end of chapter 12, when my tests started failing. The strange thing is that the tests which fail seem to be unrelated to the changes I made in chapter 12.

There are three failures and one error, and they are also duplicated by the local server when manually checked in the browser. Basically the logged_in_user before action doesn't seem to work, but only with some of the model actions, not all. I've tried to trace it with the debugger and tried to revert back to pre-chapter 12 commits (which all definitely worked) but I'm having trouble with database migrations and stuff and only introducing more and more errors. Below is the error log, my users controller, application controller and sessions helper. I feel like the error must be in one of those.

Many many thanks in advance for your help!

> > FAIL["test_should_redirect_update_when_not_logged_in", UsersControllerTest, 2016-03-06 05:58:45 -0800] 
> >     test_should_redirect_update_when_not_logged_in#UsersControllerTest
> >     (1457272725.92s)
> >             Expected true to be nil or false
> >             test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:27:in `block in '
> >
> > ERROR["test_should_redirect_destroy_when_not_logged_in", UsersControllerTest, 2016-03-06 05:58:45 -0800] 
> >     test_should_redirect_destroy_when_not_logged_in#UsersControllerTest
> >     (1457272725.96s) NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined
> >     method `admin?' for nil:NilClass
> >                 app/controllers/users_controller.rb:77:in`admin_user'
> >                 test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
> >                 test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:46:in`block in '
> >             app/controllers/users_controller.rb:77:in `admin_user'
> >             test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:47:in`block (2 levels) in '
> >             test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:46:in `block in '
> >
> > FAIL["test_should_redirect_edit_when_not_logged_in", UsersControllerTest, 2016-03-06 05:58:46 -0800] 
> >     test_should_redirect_edit_when_not_logged_in#UsersControllerTest
> >     (1457272726.03s)
> >             Expected true to be nil or false
> >             test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:21:in `block in '
> >
> > FAIL["test_successful_edit_with_friendly_forwarding", UsersEditTest, 2016-03-06 05:58:46 -0800] 
> >     test_successful_edit_with_friendly_forwarding#UsersEditTest
> >     (1457272726.07s)
> >             Expected response to be a redirect to <[removed link]/users/633107804/edit> but was a redirect to <[removed
> >     link]/users/633107804>.
> >             Expected "[removed link]users/633107804/edit" to be === "[removed link]/users/633107804".
> >             test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:22:in `block in '

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user, only: :destroy
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :following, :followers]

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to_users_url
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
   if @user.save
     @user.send_activation_email
     flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
     redirect_to root_url
   else
     render 'new'
   end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.following.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end


end
```

And the application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

include SessionsHelper

private

#confirms a logged in user. Now placed in the application controller so both teh user controller and microposts controller can use it
def logged_in_user
  unless logged_in?
    store_location
    flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
    redirect_to login_url
  end
end

end
```

And the sessions helper:

```
module SessionsHelper
  #logs in the given user
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # returns the current logged-in user (if any)
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  # returns true if the user is logged in, and false otherwise
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  #Saves a user id and remember token digest to cookies 
  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    #Code to save cookies with 20 year expiry ("permanent") and "signed" so it can't be accessed by third party
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end

  # runs the forget method and removes remember tokens from cookies
  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  # logs out the given user
  def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  # Redirects to stored location after trying to edit while logged out and then logging in
  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:forwarding_url] || default)
    session.delete(:forwarding_url)
  end

  # Stores the URL trying to be accessed
  def store_location
    session[:forwarding_url] = request.url if request.get?
  end

end
```

Userscontrollertest:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  def setup
    @user = users(:Joe)
    @other_user = users(:Jane)
  end

  test "should redirect to index when not logged in" do
    get :index
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should redirect edit when not logged in" do
    get :edit, id: @user
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should redirect update when not logged in" do
    patch :update, id: @user, user: { name: @user.name, email: @user.email }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should redirect edit when logged in as wrong user" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    get :edit, id: @user
    assert flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end

  test "should redirect update when logged in as the wrong user" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    patch :update, id: @user, user: { name: @user.name, email: @user.email }
    assert flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end

  test "should redirect destroy when not logged in" do
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      delete :destroy, id: @user
      end
        assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should redirect destroy when logged in as a non-admin" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      delete :destroy, id: @user
    end
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end
end
```

Comment: Please show your `UsersControllerTest`.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the reply! I've added it, but I would be surprised if that's the issue because previewing in the browser also duplicates the error (ie the redirects and friendly forwarding don't work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comparing your code to what I have in my tutorial code, try changing the order of the `before_action` statements in your `UsersController` and see if that works:

Before:

```
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user, only: :destroy
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :following, :followers]
```

After:

```
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :following, :followers]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user, only: :destroy
```

All the `before_action` statements are run in the order they are defined in the controller, so for the `update` action, you're currently running the `correct_user` filter first, which calls `current_user?(@user)`, which calls `current_user`:

```
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end
```

At that point in your tests, since you haven't logged in a user yet, you don't have a `session[:user_id]`, so that `if` statement fails, and you also don't have a `cookies.signed[:user_id]`, so the `elsif` statement fails, leaving you with a `nil` return value and `@current_user` not being set.

At some point in your request in the test, you seem to be finding its way over to the `admin_user` method, which is calling `current_user.admin?`, and since at this point `current_user` is `nil`, you're getting the `NoMethodError: undefined method admin?' for nil:NilClass` that you're seeing.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot Paul! I was so close - I thought it was an issue with the current_user method but didn't think about the order of the before actions! Much appreciated - thanks for taking the time to help out.